# Squeaky Retina MacBook Pro upon pressure to bottom-right corner

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro

I just got my new Retina MBP that I ordered online. I noticed a minor squeaky/creaky sound whenever I apply some pressure on the bottom right corner and beside the right speaker. The sound also generates when I press on the trackpad on very few occassions.

I am sure this is not normal, is there a way to fix this ? I tried finding a T5 screw driver but the screws used in the rMBP have 5 edges rather than 6. So I cannot really tighten it myself to check whether that fixes it.

I am currently in an international country that does not have a specific Apple Store, just a wholesaler that tells me to go to the service center and check whats the problem there. I do not want my new laptop to be scratched or mishandled, so I prefer doing it on my own. However I am not sure what I can do to fix it myself. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This believe this is normal. I have experienced the same in my unibody non-retina MBP.

I carefully studied the back cover for **wear marks**. Then I took a close look at the logic board without touching it.

- On the whole logic board you'll find **tiny elastic sticks**. They can be pushed a little. These sticks hold the aluminum bottom off the logic board.
- I did not take any chances, therefore I applied **insulating tape** on every place of the aluminum bottom that the sticks can contact. Also I did not want to open the cover multiple times :)
- Apply the tape **again** as it easily wears out.

Now the MBP does not make any of the previous mechanic noises anymore.

[image]

[image]

This is what the back cover looked like when I was done.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for such a comprehensive answer !!
I have a question though, if the squeaks are coming from the right side, would it be enough to only tape the bottom right side then ? And what type of screw driver did you use ? And does this void the warranty ?

Comment: @Fendi Simply applying the tape should be enough (it was for me). I used a [Philips #00](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/Phillips-00-Screwdriver/IF145-006?utm_source=ifixit_guide&utm_medium=guide_intro&utm_content=required_items&utm_term=macbook_pro_15%22_retina_display_mid_2012) screwdriver for the non-retina MBP. The retina MBP uses [pentalobe screws](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/MacBook-Pro-and-Air-5-Point-Pentalobe-Screwdriver/IF145-090?utm_source=ifixit_guide&utm_medium=guide_intro&utm_content=required_items&utm_term=macbook_pro_15%22_retina_display_mid_2012) for the backcover, I think.

Comment: @Fendi You should check out the [teardown of the retina MBP](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Retina-Display-Mid-2012-Teardown/9462/1) by iFixit.

Comment: I might try this when I get the correct screw driver, might be hard to find. Or maybe just go to a service center and see if they can do it for me ... not sure

Comment: @Fendi It's really easy to do yourself. You don't need to pay a service to do it for you. All you need is a screwdriver, tape and ~15 min. :)

Comment: Im still waiting for the screw driver to arrive, I had to order it for I couldnt find a suitable one in stores around me !! However I went to a service center, and the guy tightened the screws a bit .. that didnt fix the problem however .. im assuming the only way to fix it is to do the method you explained above ?

Comment: @Fendi That's Apple. As the average user has a high potential to break stuff, they try to hide it or make it hard to access. Examples: 1) Apple started hiding the `~/Library` directory in Lion. 2) Apple started using rarely used pentalobe screws in the iPhone to make it difficult for non-apple stors to repair iPhones. Apple wants to control the user experience from end-to-end and believes it can provide better customer support than third-party resellers.

Comment: @Fendi I do believe that unless the interior design of the unibody MBP changes, my method is currently the only way of fixing this. The wear marks are a *physical proof* of what's going on here.

Comment: Yes sadly .. I will have to wait for the screw driver and try your method ... I will then reply back here and mark your answer as correct if I hopefully resolved the problem

Comment: I can confirm that this method works like a charm !! THANK YOU

Comment: Btw, how many pieces of tape did you apply at each point ?

Comment: @Fendi I've used 2-3. The first time I only used one strip per application. As that wasn't enough, I had to re-open my MBP and redo the whole procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Before you are doing all the work descripted in here:

Just try loosening the screws a bit.
That completely removed the squeaky/creaky sound from my rMBP15, without even opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the "squeaky" bottom cover of my retina macbook pro 15" model by using a qtip to apply a very tiny amount of WD40 to each if the retractable metal standoffs on the motherboard.  I went back and forth between rubbing the qtip on the metal standoff and then using the other side of the qtip to rapidly move the standoff spring action up and down to work in the wd40.  After doing this for all of the standoffs my bottom cover no longer makes any noise.

I cannot stress enough that I used a TINY amount of WD40 and was EXTREMELY careful not to use enough that it could possibly run off into other parts of the motherboard.  WD40 is no electrically conductive.

Also, I see that the accepted solution is to put electrical tape on the bottom of the case itself.  I see that this has worked for other people but in my case it was clear that the noise was coming from unlubricated springs in those standoffs.  Also, you can see that there are cutouts in that black sheet that is attached to the metal bottom case specifically where these standoffs make contact with the case.  The standoffs are metal and the case is metal, so I did not feel it was appropriate to put electrical tape in between these two metal surfaces to block electrical conductivity seeing as the laptop was clearly designed to allow for this metal-on-metal contact.